# something wrong with answer sorting?

Tags: support, answers, sorting

I thought answers were always to be sorted in descending order, yet since a few days I'm seeing this kind of ordering, for example on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806906/how-do-i-test-if-a-variable-is-a-number-in-bash): what is going on here?

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: Check the active|oldest|votes tabs.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sure you didn't accidentally sort by active? That causes the answers to be arranged in descending order of last active (last posted/modified).

**See here (the fix is to sort by Votes):**

[image]

Comment: ok silly of me, I never used those tabs before I guess... must have click on it accidentally...

Comment: Yeah, problem is that it sticks. One misclick and it stays for good until you click a different tab.